# default location for virtual environment - ansible

Tags: ansible

In the [pip module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html) of ansible, the parameter, `virtualenv`, it says,

> An optional path to a virtualenv directory to install into.

What if we dont give this parameter, where will this virtualenv be created ?

Like this,

---

```
- hosts: local
  tasks:
  - pip:
      name: django
      virtualenv_command: virtualenv
```

What would this play do ? Will it create any virtualenv ? If yes, then where ? its path ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify a `virtualenv`, it will simply install the package at system level.

([Reference in module code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/bc4a8db/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/language/pip.py#L444))

Comment: means no virtual env ?

Comment: Yes, if you want a virtualenv you have to specify it's path.